# SQL Stored Procedure - replace a result column with value from existing table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm having trouble figuring out how to replace a value on a stored procedure result based on values from another table. I have a table [LOG] that is formatted as such:

```
TIME STAMP, TAG, DESCRIPTION, EVENTCODE, SUBEVENTCODE
30-Aug-2013 10:14:10, TAG X, HI TEMP FAULT, 3, 16 
30-Aug-2013 10:12:10, TAG Y, HI PRESS FAULT, 3, 16
...
```

And another table [EVENTS] which basically describes what the EVENTCODE is:

```
EVENT, DESCRIPTION 
1, FAULT
2, LOGIC
3, ALARM
```

I would like to have the stored procedure retrieve 2000 entries (rows) of the 1st table and, instead of showing EVENTCODE as a number, display the description contained in the 2nd table on the result. 
e.g:

```
TIME STAMP, TAG, DESCRIPTION, EVENTCODE, SUBEVENTCODE
30-Aug-2013 10:14:10, TAG X, HI TEMP FAULT, ALARM, 16
```

Reason is I have another software that interacts with the result of the stored procedure, and wouldn't like to create another table to hold these results within the database.

Here is what the stored procedure looks like so far:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get2kEvents]
AS
BEGIN

SELECT TOP 2000 CAST(datepart(day,TIME_STAMP) as char(2)) + '-' + 
CAST(datename(month,TIME_STAMP) as char(3)) + '-' + 
CAST(datepart(year,TIME_STAMP) as char(4))+ ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,TIME_STAMP,108)
as 'TIME STAMP', 
[TAG], 
[DESCRIPTION],
[EVENTCODE], 
[SUBEVENTCODE]
FROM [Arc_DB].[dbo].[LOG]
ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC

END
GO
```

I appreciate your assistance. Sorry if this is too basic, but I wasn't able to figure out a solution for this while browsing this and other websites.

Cheers.

TM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `join` the two tables. ie:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 CAST(datepart(day,TIME_STAMP) as char(2)) + '-' + 
CAST(datename(month,TIME_STAMP) as char(3)) + '-' + 
CAST(datepart(year,TIME_STAMP) as char(4))+ ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,TIME_STAMP,108)
as 'TIME STAMP', 
[TAG], 
[DESCRIPTION],
Events.Description, 
[SUBEVENTCODE]
FROM [Arc_DB].[dbo].[LOG]
     inner join events on log.eventcode = events.event
ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. This resolved my issue. I also extended the code a little bit to bring some other tables. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 CAST(datepart(day,TIME_STAMP) as char(2)) + '-' + 
CAST(datename(month,TIME_STAMP) as char(3)) + '-' + 
CAST(datepart(year,TIME_STAMP) as char(4))+ ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,TIME_STAMP,108)
as 'TIME STAMP', 
[TAG], 
L.[DESCRIPTION],

E.[DESCRIPTION], 

[SUBEVENTCODE]
FROM [Arc_DB].[dbo].[LOG] L
INNER JOIN [Arc_DB].[dbo].[EVENTS] E ON E.EVENT = L.EVENTCODE
ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a left join and check for missing codes:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 CAST(datepart(day,TIME_STAMP) as char(2)) + '-' + 
CAST(datename(month,TIME_STAMP) as char(3)) + '-' + 
CAST(datepart(year,TIME_STAMP) as char(4))+ ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,TIME_STAMP,108)
as 'TIME STAMP', 
[TAG], 
[DESCRIPTION],
CASE WHEN EVENTS.DESCRIPTION IS NULL
     THEN 'UNKNOWN CODE '+CAST(LOG.EVENTCODE AS VARCHAR(20)) 
     ELSE EVENTS.DESCRIPTION
END AS [Event Type],
[EVENTCODE], 
[SUBEVENTCODE]
FROM LOG
LEFT JOIN EVENTS ON EVENTS.EVENT= LOG.EVENTCODE

ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC
```